# smtp is not working on for loops

Tags: c#, email, smtp, windows-services

I want to send an email to more than 2 people using my own database. So I use for loop to send an email. And it is sent well to a first person(mail_data.Rows[0][0]), but not for the second person.(mail_data.Rows[1][0]) The code stops before smtp.Send(mm). Second person's email is exactly correct. I have no idea why the code stops there.

```
    private void Email()
    {
        //get the data from database
        DataTable data = GetData();
        DataTable email_data = GetEmailData();

        data.TableName = "Employee_Data";

                 ....


                String from = "aa@gmail.com";

                for (int i = 0; i <= email_data.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    String to = email_data.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(from, to))
                    {
                        this.WriteToFile(to);
                        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
                        {

                            mm.Subject = "Fresh NSO Updated List";

                            mm.AlternateViews.Add(body);
                            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "NSOList.xlsx"));
                            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

                            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                            credentials.UserName = "aa@gmail.com";
                            credentials.Password = "aa";
                            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                            smtp.Port = 587;

                            this.WriteToFile("beforeSend");
                            Thread.Sleep(1000);
          //just stop here on second loop, 
                            smtp.Send(mm);
                            this.WriteToFile("Sent!");
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by stops? Is an exception thrown? Is it hung on send? Did you really just embed your real password into this Stack Overflow question? Terrible idea. You need to change your password immediately.

Comment: Instead of separate messages, could you not just add all the recipients to the BCC field of a single email?

Comment: @mason oh yeah..It was my mistake I change right after see this one..thanks. When I execute the code, it hung on send on the second for loop.

Comment: @Andy because I need to hide the list of the recipient to the others

Comment: That's what BCC is for: Blind Carbon Copy. The recipients can't see the addresses of others. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Andy I success to do it thanks! But is there any way they can see their address, not for the others' address? because in To part in email, they said <no receiver>

Comment: I think it's fairly common practice to put your (the sender's) email in the to field, just to it isn't blank. If there is a better solution I hope someone will mention it.

Comment: @Andy Okay...thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending individual emails to each recipient, when they are all the same content, you should use the BCC (blind carbon copy) field to send the same email to multiple recipients and still provide privacy for all of their email addresses.

You can set the `to` field to your (the sender's) email address so that it is addressed to someone.

This is a more efficient solution and has the same overall result.